# From Weyl groups to Weyl groupoids?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm trying to find a framework where the choices in the classical construction of a root system of a semi-simple lie algebra are not needed.

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple lie algebra.

> Definition (**Weyl groupoid**): Let $\mathcal{W}$ be the following groupoid:
>
> - $Obj(\mathcal{W})=\{\mathfrak{b}\subset \mathfrak{g} | \space \mathfrak{ b} \text{ is a maximal solvable algebra}\}$
> - $Mor(\mathcal{W}) = \{Ad(e^x):\mathfrak{b}_1 \to \mathfrak{b}_2 \space |\space x \in \mathfrak{g}\}$

Here's what I like about this so far:

- Objects in $\mathcal{W}$ are in 1-1 correspondence with choosing: **cartan subalgebra** & **Weyl chamber** (root basis).
- Morally there's sort of an exponential map $exp: \mathcal{W} \to
     G/B$ (this is not meant to be a precise statement).

A couple of questions:

> 1. Is this the correct categorification?
> 2. How do I get the weyl group out of this?
> 3. I read somewhere that a choice of borel subalgebra is equivalent to a choice of complex structure on the complexified tangent bundle of $G/B$. Can this groupoid be interpreted in terms of a groupoid of complex structures?
> 4. Where can I find more about this kind of construction?

Comment: It's easier to have this discussion on the Lie group rather than Lie algebra level. There for $G$ a compact connected Lie group you can consider the groupoid whose objects are maximal tori and whose morphisms are conjugations. Every object in this groupoid is isomorphic, and all of their automorphism groups are the Weyl group.

Comment: I would normally choose morphisms to be automorphisms seen as elements of $GL(\mathfrak{g})$ instead of exponentials - this is not a big deal as long as you work over the real or complex numbers.  To get a Weyl group, you consider a groupoid whose objects are Cartan subalgebras, together with the obvious functor from $\mathcal{W}$.  Fibers are naturally W-torsors.

Comment: @S.Carnahan That's great! Can I make this geometric? i.e. is there a weyl group torsor $W \to G/B \to G/T$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Warning:** This answer went through a massive editing.

---

This answer does not regard the specific questions asked, but the motivation behind: finding a framework where the choices in the classical construction of a root system of a semi-simple Lie algebra are not needed.

---

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra and $G=\text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})^0$.
Let $C^+$ be the set of pairs (Cartan,Borel) where the Cartan subalgebra is contained in the Borel subalgebra ($C^+$ is a subset of a product of two Grassmannians of $\mathfrak{g}$). Note that $G$ acts transitively on $C^+$, stabilizers being centralizers of maximal tori.

It is not hard to see that the centralizer of the $G$-action on $C^+$ is isomorphic to the Weyl group (it acts trivially on the Cartan coordinate and transitively on all Borels including a given Cartan). Let's call it "the choice free Weyl group" $W$.

There is a natural vector bundle $H$ over $C^+$, the fiber over (Cartan,Borel) being the vector space underlying the Cartan. Note that (since the stabilizer of a point acts trivially on its fiber) the vector space of all $G$-invariant sections is isomorphic to each fiber. Let's call it "the choice free Cartan" $\mathfrak{h}$. We get a natural action of $W$ on $\mathfrak{h}$.

Note that the dual space, $\mathfrak{h}^*$, could be identified with the space of invariant sections to the dual vector bundle. We can single out those invariant sections which are in the root system at each fiber and obtain "the choice free root system" $\Phi$. Note that the second coordinate in $C^+$ is a Borel. This gives a choice of positivity at each fibers, thus we can also single out "the choice free positive roots" $\Phi^+$.

---

For each parabolic type we can consider the space of parabolic subalgebras of this given type $P$. Note that between two such, $P,P'$, either there exists a unique $G$-equivariant map or none. If there exists such we will say $P\leq P'$.
We may regard a $G$-equivariant maps $C^+\to P$ as a simplex whose faces are the simplices $C^+\to P'$ for each $P'$ such that $P\leq P'$. 
We will get a simplicial complex on which $W$ acts, "the choice free Coxeter complex".

---

The following is unrelated, just a comment regarding the question's title. 
The name "Weyl Groupoid" should be reserved to the following category.

- Objects: Cartan subalgebras.
- Morphisms: A morphism between two Cartan algebras is a Lie-algebra isomorphism which could be extended to a global automorphism in $G$.

This is a connected groupoid and the isotropy group of every object is isomorphic to the Weyl group.

---

**Remark:** I was tacitly assuming above that everything is over an algebraically closed field, or split. One can easily adjust the definitions to handle the general case.

Comment: The isotropy group of a Cartan in your groupoid is not the Weyl group; you also get elements coming from diagram automorphisms.  For $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$, minus transpose is an algebra automorphism preserving the usual Cartan, but doesn't come from an element of the Weyl group.

Comment: (Deleted a foolish comment:  I misread and thought that $C$ was a particular Cartan, rather than the variety of all of them.)

Comment: @Ben Webster, thanks, definition corrected. Really I have in mind the variety of  centralizer of max tori in $G$ where $G$ is connected, hence the mistake.

Comment: @user89334 your edit is very helpful thanks!

Comment: @SaalHardali I made a major edition in order to make the "choice free construction" clear. I decided to neglect your wish for "categorfication" as the natural setting, I find, is simply to consider $G$-equivariant objects.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit unclear to me precisely what you want, but the usual solution is take the abstract Cartan (discussed a bit [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/4980/66)), which is defined to be $\mathbb{T}=B/[B,B]$ for any Borel $B$.  This is canonical, since any two Borels are conjugate, and every Borel is self-normalizing so $\mathbb{T}$ is unique up to the map induced by conjugation by an element of $B$.  The action of the Weyl group is given by looking at all the isomorphisms induced between $\mathbb{T}$ and any fixed torus $T$ by all the different Borels containing $T$ (which are all conjugate under $N(T)$).  Composing one of these isomorphisms with the inverse of another gives all the elements of the Weyl group.

Comment: As the sidebar informs, this point of view is also discussed in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103751/about-the-intrinsic-definition-of-the-weyl-group-of-complex-semisimple-lie-algeb .

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful. Mainly what I was after is a way to remember what choice gives me what and in what sense are they equivalent. S. Carnahan gave me the idea of encoding it in a torsor $\mathcal{W} \to G/B \to G/T$ where a point in the base is a cartan subalgebra and a point in the total space is a borel subalgebra. The weyl group acts transitively on the fibers. Does this work?

Comment: I must say that I fail to see how any of this is choice free. Surely, everything here is independent of the choices made, but choices are made.

Comment: @user89334 Fair enough.  Like I said, I wasn't really sure what the user wanted.

Comment: In any case it seems that my impression, that it was all about making the definitions choice free, wasn't what the OP wanted, and what you wote satisfied him.

Comment: @BenWebster I accepted yours since it really gave me the last piece I was missing. I have the impression that the *true* definition is in some sense the one  S. Carnahan eluded to, namely, let the groupoid in my question be called $\mathcal{B}$ and let $\mathcal{W}$ be the *correct* weyl groupoid with objetcs cartan subalgebras and morphisms adjoint actions of $\mathfrak{g}$. There's a functor $\mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{W}$ which takes a borel to its abstract cartan. The automorphism group of that functor is the weyl group.

Comment: @Saal Hardali that could be a very good reason indeed to accept the answer, only it is not correct and had not claimed by anyone. In fact there is no such canonical functor as you describe. On the other hand there are $W$ many functors $\mathcal{W}\to\mathcal{B}$ on which the abstract Weyl group I described in my answer acts. These functors could be thought of as choices of Weyl chambers in the abstract Cartan.

Comment: @user89334 Thanks! I still don't really understand why there's no functor from $\mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{W}$

Comment: @Saal, instead of me trying to convience you there isn't, can you try to write down one? Incidentally the last sentence in my previous comment is false as stated. also I earased a false comment I made here.  There is a correct conceptual reason for which I wrote these wrong statements, and I will edit it into my answer when I'll find the time.

Comment: @user89334 Thanks. Silly me, I do understand now why my construction is wrong. However, as a non expert on this topic I'm pretty confused by some of the wrong remarks on this thread. I feel like there ought to be at least one satisfying invariant geometric way to incorparate all the interrelated information contained in the borel algebras cartan algebras and weyl group. I'm sorry to have accepted this answer on the false premise that I had such a construction. Your edited part might be what i'm looking for but i still need to think that through. Thanks again!

Comment: @SaalHardali You can change what the accepted answer is.